# What does a double await mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

I was looking at some codebase and found this. Notice there are two await next to each other

```
 await  await fetch(fetchUrl, { method: 'get' , cache:"no-store" , headers: {
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
  }})
     .then(res => res.blob())
     .then(res => {
        const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(res);
        var .................
```

Is it a bug? Or what is its meaning?

Comment: "*Is it a bug?*" technically it's valid code. But it's meaningless  - you cannot get a promise from a promise. Seems like a mistake or misunderstanding unless there is something weird being done with thenable objects. In which case, I suspect it's still a problem because somebody made a weird thenable.

Comment: `await`-ing a non-Promise value returns the value itself. So, `await`-ing the result of an `await` is superfluous, but doesn't cause problems...

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but the `await` when using `fetch` is required. `fetch` returns a response in two steps: first the headers (the first `await` gets you this far, you cannot get the body yet), then the response body is returned in a second step. The second `await` gets this. More of this here: https://rapidapi.com/guides/fetch-api-async-await